# e2e test fails when expecting form to be valid

Tags: angular, validation, e2e-testing

I am running an **e2e test** and it fails on one of my components, specifically on the **expect**. My form should be **valid** after filling it so.

This is the test:

```
  it("1: Should create a new sitter", async () => {
        browser.get('/register-sitter');
        // Do something
        element(by.id('firstname')).sendKeys('Susan');
        element(by.id('lastname')).sendKeys('Winston');
        element(by.id('birthdate')).sendKeys('4/18/2018');
        element(by.id('gender')).all(by.tagName('mat-radio-button')).get(0).click();
        element.all(by.css('mat-select')).each(function (eachElement) {
            eachElement.click();                    //select the select
            browser.driver.sleep(500);              //wait for the renderings to take effect
            element(by.css('mat-option')).click();  //select the first mat-option
            browser.driver.sleep(500);              //wait for the renderings to take effect
        });
        element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('s.w@com');
        element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('susu123W');
        element(by.id('register')).click();
        element(by.css('form')).submit();
        // Expect something

   expect(element(by.css('form')).getAttribute('class')).toContain('ng-valid');
   });
```

Comment: Just looking at your code quickly, is it correct you're clicking on 'register' and then forcing your form to submit? Also, just thinking here, maybe put a browser.driver.sleep after your last input, maybe the events are happening too quickly for the digest to occur to add the class to your form

Comment: Will you be able to add the error you get when you run above test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row of your test is an asynchronous call, if you try to assert the result before the previous call ended you will probably get errors.

Instead of using the `browser.driver.sleep`, you could take advantage of the returned promises by the protractor functions and synchronise what should by synchronized.

For example this code :

```
element(by.id('firstname')).sendKeys('Susan');
element(by.id('lastname')).sendKeys('Winston');
```

Would be replaced by :

```
element(by.id('firstname')).sendKeys('Susan')
.then(() => element(by.id('lastname')).sendKeys('Winston'));
```

This way you could do your validations once all previous actions are completed.

Comment: this way I would have a huge nested promises right, I just want to make sure I am doing it right ? I mean each promise would be closed at the end of the code block, so it would look something like this: `expect(element(by.css('form')).getAttribute('class')).toContain('ng-valid'))))))))))});`

Comment: Not necessarily, as the `then` function returns a promise you could do `promise.then().then()...then();`. You just need to return the promise inside your then inline function to properly chain your promises.

Answer (score 0):

Do try with

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

before expect call.